# Mail API - SSL message - how to set sender email correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've just tried example code for SSL shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/); it is much interesting and I tested it; For some reason it doesn't set sender back email address but in GMail I can see

> from:  recipienttestemail@gmail.com
>
> to:    recipienttestemail@gmail.com

so sender Email is ignored or something :( Both are recipient's one :S How to set sender Email to see it in GMail messages correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You might find [this related question][1] helpful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429818/spring-3-0-simplemailmessage-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setFrom(), is supposed to do that but gmail's smtp server is not supposed to take it into account and only uses the smtp account.

And that's a good thing not to be able to use gmail to forge spams.

Comment: Security is great; But what about reply message ability?  I mean "reply to sender"? Is there some way to place sender email? Maybe not SSL but something other way?

Comment: not to my best knowledge, and I don't see how a client side solution could solve a server side constraint.